Attach Event handler to a Form created from a dll loaded at run-time
I'm looking for a way to handle close event and fetch one return parameter.
I can't change the way that WinFormApp.dll is being run.
Private Sub ShowWinFormApp() Handles Button1.Click

 ' launching new WinForm app from within another app 

  Dim InvTrack As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("\\NetworkPath\WinFormApp.dll"))
  Dim oType As System.Type
  Dim pControl As System.Object
  Dim Params As New List(Of Object)

  Params.Add(Param1)
  Params.Add(Param2)
  oType = InvTrack.GetType("WinFormApp.FrmMain")
  pControl = Activator.CreateInstance(oType, Params)

     'here i'd like to add handler to catch my event 
  AddHandler pControl.ImDone, AddressOf ReLaunch  
    'this not working, saying that Element `ImDone` is not an event of element `Object`

  Application.Run(pControl)
End Sub

In WinFormApp I tried like this:
Public Class FrmMain
   Public Event ImDone As EventHandler(Of ImDoneEventArgs)

    Public Sub Test() Handles Button1.Click
       RaiseEvent ImDone (Me, New ImDoneEventArgs With {.RetVal = 54})
       Application.Exit()
    End Sub

    Public Class ImDoneEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs
        Public Property RetVal As Integer
    End Class
End class 


pControl was declared as Object. The Object type doesn't have an ImDone member. You'll need a get the actual type, not just an object, to use there.

Are you referencing that DLL in your project? If so, why are you using Reflection at all instead of just creating an instance of the WinFormApp.FrmMain type like you would any other type? If you're not referencing it, why are you not doing so? Not to say that there can't be reasons but, if you'd like us to help with your issue then we need all the relevant information. If you do have to use Reflection to create the object, you need to use Reflection to handle the event as well.

@jmcilhinney
Well, the general assumptions for this tool are that many users run MyApp.exe file instaled locally on their PCs. MyApp is launching different dll files. Each dll is a standalone winform application. All dll's are located on network share. I'cant change the way it works due to company security policy = I can't distibute anything to end user PC.

Actually, sorry, I missed the Assembly.Load call somehow. In that case, the answer is that you need to handle the event by Reflection. Once you start down the Reflection path, you have to stay on it. You can't magically start using a reference of a type that your application doesn't know exists. You need to research how to do that, do it and then post a new question if what you do doesn't work.

You also can't pass an Object reference to Application.Run. It will only accept a Form or ApplicationContext reference. You don;t have the former so you'll need to use the latter.

An example, assuming the code you have posted matches the real scenario.
You cannot use AddHandler when the target event and the Type of its provider are unknown in the current assembly.  Activator.CreateInstance() returns an object Type that only exposes its basic methods.
You can cast the object to its base class, the Form class. This Type is known to both assemblies. Of course, the base class doesn't expose custom events, but you can use call its ShowDialog() method to present the Form.
You cannot call Application.Run() directly if a message loop is already running. But you don't need to, ShowDialog() already does that for you, in a compatible way.
To create an event handler for the custom event, you can again use Reflection to get the related EventInfo, associate an EventHandler to the method that is called when the event is raised, then call Delegate.CreateDelegate() passing the [EventInfo].EventHandlerType and the handler's method Target, to generate a compatible delegate.
Now you can add the event handler to an event of your instance of the FrmMain object, calling [EventInfo].AddEventHandler(), passing the object that provides the event (the FrmMain object) and the event delegate:
Dim FrmMain As Form = Nothing
Dim FrmMainEvent As EventInfo = Nothing
Dim _EventDelegate As [Delegate] = Nothing
Dim _EventHandler As EventHandler(Of EventArgs) = Sub(s, e) ReLaunch(s, e)

Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes("WinFormApp.dll"))
Dim formType = asm.GetType("WinFormApp.FrmMain")
If formType Is Nothing Then Throw New Exception("FrmMain Type not found")

Dim instance = Activator.CreateInstance(formType, {Param1, Param2})
If instance IsNot Nothing Then
    FrmMain = DirectCast(instance, Form)
    FrmMainEvent = instance.GetType().GetEvent("ImDone")
    If FrmMainEvent IsNot Nothing Then
        _EventDelegate = [Delegate].CreateDelegate(
            FrmMainEvent.EventHandlerType, _EventHandler.Target, _EventHandler.Method
         )
        FrmMainEvent.AddEventHandler(instance, _EventDelegate)
    End If

    FrmMain.ShowDialog()
End If


As a note, you could also use an Action delegate Type, which could simplify your code a little.

When the event is raised, the specified delegate is called.
You should remove the event handler at this point, calling [EventInfo].RemoveEventHandler(), passing the instance of the object that provided the event (the FrmMain instance you have generated) and the delegate that was associated to the event.
The EventArgs object is also a custom Type, so you can again retrieve the value of its Properties via Reflection:

I'm not sure for what purpose the code in this event handler serves. The Form is set to null (Nothing) just because you may want to test its existence later. You may have closed it explicitly or disposed of it somewhere. Checking whether it's disposed may not give a reliable result

Public Sub ReLaunch(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If FrmMainEvent IsNot Nothing AndAlso _EventDelegate IsNot Nothing Then
        FrmMainEvent.RemoveEventHandler(FrmMain, _EventDelegate)
    End If
    Debug.WriteLine(e.GetType().GetProperty("RetVal").GetValue(e))

    _EventDelegate = Nothing
    FrmMainEvent = Nothing
    FrmMain = Nothing
End Sub


I have still so much to learn. Thanks for this it's perfect. Only thing to change was swith from  FrmMain = Nothing to FrmMain.Dispose() because in the first case old form was still visible and also new one opened on each close.

I've added a note about it
